# How can I remove an extra (undesired) block item in irssi with advanced window list?

Tags: irssi

I am seeing an extra block item in irssi, when advanced window list is used. I am wondering how do I remove it?

I am seeing, on the status bar, the following:

```
[1 (status)] [Extra block containing server A / nick] [2 first channel in server]
```

I assume the extra block is there to help organize the channel blocks if a user is connected to multiple servers. Then, the arrangement would appear like so:

```
[1 (status)] [Server A / Nick A] [2 Chan 1] [Server B / Nick B] [3 Chan 2]
```

How do I remove the `[Server X / Nick X]` blocks from the status bar in irssi when advanced window list is loaded?

---

Steps to reproduce:

1. move config, default_theme in `~/.irssi` to some other location
2. `irssi`
3. `/connect irc.freenode.net`
4. `/join #freenode`
5. `/source load adv_windowlist.pl`
6. `/toggle awl_viewer`
7. Notice there are exactly 3 items in the second line of the status bar.

(1) `[1 Status]` (2) `[freenode (Server name) | user-name]` (3) `[2 #freenode]`

Element #2 is the element in question.

---

I was wondering whether there was a setting which could toggle the "organizer blocks" off, or I would have to go into the code to make some modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the content of the file `adv_windowlist.pl`. In the beginning, it lists various options and keys that we can change or toggle. From experimentation, it was discovered that awl_display_header is the key to change.

Further, look at `/help format` for information on how to delete a key. (I was not able to set the key to the null string).

Try `/format -delete awl_display_header.`